# Visual Studio 2013. Creating ActiveX. Add Method wizard not working as expected

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, activex, wizard

This is very frustrating. Im trying to create an ActiveX control using Visual Studio 13 Professional edition.

Im selecting New Project->MFC ActiveX Control

I click the Finish button and I get all the files required for an activeX control. This compiles ok. It doesn't do anything but the framework is there.

Its when I use the wizard to add a function that I find a problem. I follow all the instructions as described in MSDN here;
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95357zak.aspx

I find the function is added in the *.cpp file and the header in the associated *.h file as expected. However, contrary to what is described in MSDN, I find;

1. the *.idl file has NOT been updated
2. the DISP_FUNCTION_ID entry has not been added

In addition there is no data type  "VARIANT_BOOL" defined in any of the dropdown boxes for creating the method function parameters. (Neither is there any string types defined)

Ive spent a bit of time on this but am completely baffled. Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Comment: *Right-click the interface node for your control* is where you went wrong.  You added the method to the class, not the interface.

Comment: Sir, you are a scholar and a gent. You are quite correct. Many thanks.